# How to make a Chrome extension pop up automatically when I enter a certain website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have created my own Chrome extension that gets compliments with ChatGPT on LinkedIn page.
The extension has 1 `manifest.json` file, 1 `popup.js` file and 1 `popup.html` file.
The manifest file is like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ChatGPT for LinkedIn Profile",
  "description": "The simple Chrome extension using to get compliments from the LinkedIn profile and show it to the user.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

And the `popup.js` file is like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
document.getElementById("ask").addEventListener('click', function(){
 
  // null here defaults to active tab of current window
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: `
    var tag = document.querySelectorAll('section.artdeco-card');
    var len = tag.length;
    [
      tag[0].innerText,
      tag[1].innerText,
      tag[2].innerText,
      tag[3].innerText,
      tag[4].innerText,
      tag[5].innerText,
    ]
    `
  }, response => {
    const pageData = response[0];
    var name, about="", activity="", experience="";
........
```

And the `popup.html` file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Chrome Extension</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px 10px;text-align:center;width:350px;">
  <h1>ChatGPT for Linkedin Compliments</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>This extension gives <b>three compliments</b> about the <b>LinkedIn profile</b> on the page.</p>
  <button id="ask" class="btn-ask" role="button">&nbsp;Get&nbsp;</button>
  <hr>
  <p>The compliments are:</p>
  <blockquote id="compliments" style="background:#eaf5ff;padding:5px; font-size: 12px;"></blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make my extension pop up automatically when I enters a specific website.
There are some articles about `manifest.json` file like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Description of my extension",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.tutorialspoint.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Please let me know how to write a `manifest.json` file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Content scripts are usually used for some interaction with a web page DOM. If you want some actions outside of the web page (such as extension popup showing), you need to use [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/). In this script, you can monitor all the opened web pages via [`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onCompleted) event listener with URL filter. On all matched URLs you can use [`chrome.action.openPopup()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-openPopup) method to show the popup.

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "permissions": ["webNavigation"],
  "action": { "default_popup": "popup.html" },
  "background": { "service_worker": "background.js" }
}
```

`background.js`:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
  async () => {
    await chrome.action.openPopup();
  },
  { url: [
    { urlMatches: 'https://example.org/' },
  ] },
);
```

`popup.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Extension</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.textContent = 'This is a test.';
});
```

Comment: I have tried to do with your code but it doesn't work. 
Could you please share me a simple extension that show up on a specific url?

Comment: @AdrianBotteon I've edited the answer. It has an extension with just 4 files that opens a popup on https://example.org/ site.

Comment: @AdrianBotteon Also, pay attention to manifest version, you need `"manifest_version": 3`.

Comment: I have changed the url match part into url of tutorials website.
And when I entered tutorialswebsite, the test extension didn't show up.

Comment: And when I inspect the extension of your code, It gives me that "TypeError: chrome.action.openPopup is not a function".

Comment: @AdrianBotteon Do you use the last Google Chrome version?

Comment: I think so.
Version 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Could you send me the script that works?

Comment: @AdrianBotteon Sorry, unfortunately I cannot understand what is wrong on your side. This 4 files works on my side without any errors. Sorry for not being able to help(