# How to open chrome extension on some behavior?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/action#method-openPopup) say that calling `chrome.action.openPopup` from the background script should open the chrome extension's popup but I get the following:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chrome.action.openPopup is not a function`

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75911358/2002580) answer but I still get this error.

I'm using Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) (x86_64), but others in the comments have said that the exact code works on their machines.

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/BWStearns/broken_chrome_ext) that demonstrates the issue.

Did chrome just get rid of support for this without updating their docs? It seems like most places I've seen this problem documented the issue is just closed and the initial asker states the proposed solution doesn't work.

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "permissions": ["webNavigation"],
  "action": { "default_popup": "popup.html" },
  "background": { "service_worker": "background.js" }
}
```

`background.js`:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
  async () => {
    await chrome.action.openPopup();
  },
  { url: [
    { urlMatches: 'https://example.org/' },
  ] },
);
```

`popup.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Extension</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.textContent = 'This is a test.';
});
```

Comment: The repo exists solely to give an easy way for someone to test it. The code is literally just the code from the linked answer right above it, but in a form that doesn't require a bunch of copy/pasting.

Comment: If you want to use a _context menu_ to perform an action you have to define the context menu in your extension manifest and code.

Comment: IF/When that repo goes away your question has no value to anyone else - which is one main purpose of the request.

Comment: Your code works on the URL defined here https://github.com/BWStearns/broken_chrome_ext/blob/main/background.js#L6. If you add `{ urlMatches: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' },` to the `url` `Array` your code works on this Web page, too.

Comment: @guest271314 it works for you? Like it triggered the popup when you navigate to example.org?

Comment: Yes. It works on this Web page, too, when I added `{ urlMatches: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' }` (preceded by a comma) to the `url` array in `background.js`. Just for completeness `{ url: [
    { urlMatches: 'https://example.org/' },
    { urlMatches: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' },
  ] }`

Comment: @BWStearns The relevant documentation does not contain all that is going on on a single page. Here's the `urlMatches` documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/events/#type-UrlFilter linked from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/webNavigation#event-onCompleted `filters`. You'll have to dive into the disparate Chrome Developer documentation - and importantly, continue your testing. Everything ain't in there (and certainly not in the same place) I'll let you know that now.

Comment: @guest271314 for me it is triggering appropriately when I visit example.org, but I am still left with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chrome.action.openPopup is not a function` on the background script output and the popup fails to open.

Comment: _"but I am still left with Uncaught (in promise) TypeError" ... on the background script output and the popup fails to open."_ I don't - on the URL's defined in `background.js`. You must have written some other code than what is in the GitHub repository, or have expectations that are not consistent with the code you (and in theory, the same I, too) are testing.

Comment: It's the identical code. Are you just loading it in as an unpacked extension?

Comment: Yes. That's all I write and use are unpacked extensions. I downloaded your GitHub repository, unzipped, loaded and tested, added a line, tested again. That's the only code we're dealing with right, the code in your GitHub repository?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry for taking so much of your time but could you share which version of chrome you're on? It looks like this api has been bugged a few times so I'm wondering if it's just a regression.
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/H5_kcgtrKbw

Comment: Chromium Version 124.0.6337.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit) from tip-of-tree a day or two ago.

Comment: @BWStearns _"It's not exposed in the stable channel yet:"_ https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/H5_kcgtrKbw/m/UEWGyzoOAQAJ must still be the case.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Feel free to drop that in an answer and I'll mark as correct. I really wish the docs didn't make it seem like it was released.

Comment: No worries. I notified you earlier everything, that is the details and minutiae, are not in the documentation. There are a few API's, proposals, etc. that don't make it to Stable. You can answer your own question. Just keep on testing and experimenting - and vetting the documentation and implementations.

Comment: The documentation says "Requires policy" (Only available to policy installed extensions).